# Why isn't motional emf valid for variable magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism

> Consider two parallel, conducting frictionless tracks are kept in gravity
>   free space as shown in the figure. A movable conductor PQ, initially
>   kept at OA, given a velocity $v= 10 m/s$ towards right. If space contains a
>   magnetic field which depends upon the distance moved by conductor
>   PQ from OA line and given by
>   $$B=-x ~\hat k$$
>   [image]The mass of conductor PQ is $1 kg$ and length of PQ is $1m$. Find emf developed.

If we use flux to calculate emf we will get $$\phi=B(xl)$$ 
$$\phi=x^2 l$$
Differentiate it to get $$V_1=2xl$$

However if I balance the lorentz force to obtain motional emf I get the wrong answer.

$$q(v\times B)=Eq $$
$$qvx=Eq$$
$$E=vx$$
Since $B$ is constant in the Y axis we can multiply it by $l$ to get the emf $V_2=vxl$

$V_1$ however is correct but I can't see why is motional emf giving the incorrect answer?

---

Note the question actually asks the total distance traveled by the rod i cut that out because it was just math no physics to ask about.

Comment: "=− ̂" is odd. Unit vectors are usually taken as dimensionless, so $\vec B$ has the wrong dimensions. I think that what's wanted is $\vec B = -k x \hat z$ in which $k$ is a constant with the units of $\text {T m}^{-1}$ and $\hat z$ is the unit vector in the $z$ direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flux calculation is wrong. I assume that $\Phi= BxL$ is the supposed to be the flux through the area OAPQ. But this is not right, because $B$ is not a constant over that area, but increases from left to right. You then substitute $x$ for $B$. Apart from the misleading notation (see comment), this is the flux density when the wire has progressed by $x$. The flux density over the area to the left of this is on average half of this.